# Android: How to make a child app (.apk file), from a parent app.

Tags: android, apk

I am working on an android project, where I take some data from user in my app (android app). Now, with this data, I want to produce a new android app. Basically, a parent android app produces a child app's .apk file by inflating some data.

How should I go for it?

Is there any 3rd party library available for this purpose?

Comment: if im getting this right, you want to make a new application(.apk) for every user who would use this parent app? So lets say if your parent app hits million users, you would have million apps(.apk) of their own?

Comment: No, each parent app, can produce as many apk files as possible (i.e. as many new apps as possible). It only depends on the will of the user. Such kind of apps do exist, for eg: [click this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.buildmlearn.toolkit)

Comment: can you explain how this would be used? I'm at a loss for imagining how this would be desired. Maybe there is a better solution

Comment: My app is for teachers, where they (teachers) can produce sample apps for their student right from their smartphones. Without going through the hassle of programming android apps. [This app is very similar to that!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.buildmlearn.toolkit)

Comment: Further, these apps produced, can be transferred to different devices of students via bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an open source code of BuildMToolKit (The example which you have mentioned) :

https://github.com/BuildmLearn/BuildmLearn-Toolkit